# Using amsthm pushes the line below proofs, lemmas, etc. to the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Like in this example

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} theorem \end{theorem}
I want this line be unpushed
\end{document}
```

Removing `\usepackage{amsthm}` fixes it, but i need the package.

Comment: Just write `\noindent I want this line be unpushed`. By default the first line on a new paragraph is indented, and `theorem` introduces automatically a new paragraph

Answer (score 1):

amsthm disables by purpose the ability of normal latex lists not to indent the line following the end of the list if there is no explicit paragraph break like an empty line by defining `\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist\@endpefalse }`

You can change this globally (for new theorems) like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} theorem \end{theorem}
I want this line be unpushed

\begin{theorem} theorem \end{theorem}

I want this line be pushed

\end{document}
```

[image]